# Clickonce deployment - check from where updates are run

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

How can I check that when I run a **clickonce** deployment, it is checking the right network deployment location for updates?

The shortcuts we have on our desktop in user profile point to the local application cache.

But every time we run the application, it checks for updates - so there must be something in the cache pointing at the network directory.

How do we confirm or check which folder is being used for updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, while the application is "installed" in the local user's profile, upon deployment you can decide where updates come from. There's nothing "in the cache pointing at the network directory", it's in the deployment description.

---

EDIT: If you just want to show in your program where updates are coming from, you can use the [ApplicationDeployment.UpdateLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.updatelocation.aspx) property.

```
Uri updateLocation = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the shortcut itself it will either be or point to an .appref-ms file. Opening that file with Notepad will give you all of the details that you're after.